# Trying to get a plot item in the layout to only show the section from the Atlas that is being shown

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas, plot

I am new to QGIS and don't know coding at all, slowly trying to pick it up.
I am creating an atlas of a area that has been surveyed over the seabed during cable instalations in the North Sea. I have managed to create a atlas with a main map showing sections of my DTM and have now added a plot item to show a side view with depth of burial of the cable below seabed. however it shows the whole plot and not just the section in the atlas block.
can i tie the view to the atlas block being shown?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS.SE! What you want to do can probably be done. What layout element are you using for the side view? How is it configured and what fields does it contain? If possible you can also share some test data that is structured like your real data, so it is easier for us to tinker with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have setup my test project as follows:

- A line layer with attributes segment_number and depth
- A polygon layer "atlas" with two atlas features
- A print layout atlas that uses the polygon layer as atlas features and has a map displaying the line and a scatterplot below which plots line.depth against line.segment_number .

This is the attribute table of the line layer:

```
fid depth segment_number
1   14    1
2   2     2
3   7     3
4   31    4
```

In the plot properties in the print layout you can set the linked map and check boxes for use only visible features in map and inside atlas feature.

[image: plot properties]

This results in this atlas (two pages)
[image: one page of atlas]

[image: another page of atlas]

This displays the atlas and the plot uses only the visible features.

Comment: Thanks will try this later.

Comment: Did it work or did you need to setup anything else?